# Traducir una sentencia de Mysql a a Eloquent, controladores laravel 5.4

Tags: mysql, laravel, consola, controller, model-view-controller

Hola todavía no se mucho sobre como pasar las consultas a laravel, tengo la siguiente (la cual corre perfectamente lo que quiero en Mysql):

consulta en mysql

> 'select distinct a.temario as Evento, count(b.id) as Participantes from
>   eventos a, users b, asistencia c where c.evento_id=a.id and c.usuario_id=b.id

y en el controlador laravel

```
public function index()
{ 

     $asistir=DB::raw('asistencia as m', 'evento as a', 'User as b') 
     ->distinct('a.temario as evento', count('b.id as Participantes from evento', 'users b', 'asistencia c'))
     ->where('c.evento_id','=',$id)

     ->paginate(10);


    return view('vistas.detalleEvento.form',["asistencia"=>$asistir]);
}
```

pero no me funciona  me podrían ayudar

Comment: Has intentado así: `return view('vistas.detalleEvento.form')->with(["asistencia"=>$asistir]);`

Comment: si lo que no me devuelve es el conteo

Comment: al count no le faltan parentesis?